# Connecting two attributes together in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I already connect my asp.net application to my SQL server database. But, i have two attributes in my database that i want to connect them together example:

```
attribute 1      attribute 2
VM-Number        Cloud-name
1                Azure
2                Amazon
```

when the VM-Number inserted to the database Cloud-Name should automatically inserted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is a definite Key-Value-Pair you might use a Lookup table

```
CREATE TABLE Attribute(AttrKey INT NOT NULL,AttrValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Attribute VALUES(1,'Azure'),(2,'Amazon');
```

Then you get the corresponding row like this

```
SELECT AttrValue FROM Attribute WHERE AttrKey=1;
```

If there is an existing table "VMs" and another existing table "Clouds" and both have a unique key, you might use a mapping table (allowing m:n relation), ...

```
CREATE TABLE VM_in_Cloud(VMID INT /*your actual data type!*/ NOT NULL
                        ,CloudID INT /*your actual data type!*/ NOT NULL);
```

... or you add a `CloudID` to your VMs-table or a VMID to your Clouds-table.